# Proving that $AB$ contains an/the identity element for $A, B\le G.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be  a group. Let $A \leq G$ and let $B \leq G$ and let $B$ be normal. let $AB = \{ ab: a\in A, b\in B\} $. How do I prove that $AB$ contains an/the identity element?

Comment: Consider $e=e.e\in AB$

Comment: so let $e \in A$ and $e \in B$. We then have $e*e*ab = e*ab= ab = ab*e=ab*e*e$ for all $a \in A$ and all $b \in B$ Is that it?

Comment: You don't need to write let $e\in A$ and $e\in B$. Instead, you say this. Let $e$ be the identity in $G$. Because $A\leq G$ and $B\leq G$, it follows that $e\in A$ and $e\in B$. Thus, by definition of the set $AB$, it follows that $ee\in AB$. But $ee=e$ since $e$ is an identity.

Answer (score 1):

Since both $A\le G$ and $B\le G$, we have that $A$ and $B$ both contain the identity $e$ in $G$, so $e=ee\in AB$.